# Maven compilation failure when switching on enum

Tags: java, maven-3, maven-compiler-plugin

I am mavenifying (is that a word?) a project whose build process has been so far based entirely on ant/shell scripts.

Consider the following enum

```
public enum ResourceType {
    A, B;
}
```

The following bean:

```
public ResourceTypeOwner {
    //set get resourceType property
}
```

And the following code snippet:

```
void foo(ResourceTypeOwner rto) {
    ResourceType resourceType = rto.getResourceType();
    switch (resourceType) {
    case A:
        handleA(resourceType); break;
    case B:
        handleB(resourceType); break;
    default:
        throw new RuntimeException("Unsupported resource type");
    }
}
```

I am getting a compilation error when building with maven:

> Cannot switch on a value of type ResourceType. Only convertible int
>   values or enum variables are permitted

The pom.xml has the following plugin configuration for compiling

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
        <configuration>
            <compilerId>eclipse</compilerId>
            <compilerVersion>1.6</compilerVersion>
            <source>1.6</source>
            <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
                <artifactId>plexus-compiler-eclipse</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </plugin>
...
</plugins>
```

Both ant (with org.eclipse.jdt.core.JDTCompilerAdapter) and eclipse build/compile fine. I am obviously doing something wrong (unless it's an unreported maven-compiler-plugin or plexus-compiler-eclipse plugin bug, which is somewhat unlikely, switching on enums is neither bad nor rocket science). Does anybody have an idea?

Additional environment details

> $mvn -version Apache Maven 3.0.4 (r1232337; 2012-01-17 10:44:56+0200)
>   Maven home: /home/d/dev/tools/apache-maven-3.0.4 Java version:
>   1.6.0_35, vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc. Java home: /opt/jdk1.6.0_35/jre Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
>   OS name: "linux", version: "3.2.0-40-generic", arch: "amd64", family:
>   "unix"

UPDATE:

Standard JDK compiler compiles the specific class successfully. Looks like an plexus-compiler-eclipse 2.2 issue.

Comment: Check whether you have only one `ResourceType` in your classpath (including dependencies). I believe that you have yet another (regular) class with the same name.

Comment: I just searched the entire mvn repository for classes with the same name. There are none. Also, it happens on two different Enums (these are the only cases that an enum is switched on the entire project). Finally renamed the enum to ResourceType123456 (with eclipse refactor). Same problem. Thx though.

Comment: do you have to use the eclipse compiler? whats wrong with the jdk one?

Comment: There are cases with generic inferring mostly that javac does not allow and ecj does. Consider <T> foo() and <T,V extends Serializable> bar() and foo calls bar in its method body. Javac forces you to add the second parameter to foo as well. I am not suggesting foo SHOULD have only one type parameter, but I did not write the entire codebase ;)

Comment: I have the same problem.  It is specific to the eclipse compiler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to reproduce and found the problem.

Turns out that the setting `org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.compliance` needs to be set to the target version in order for it
to be able to recognize `java.lang.Enum`.

This setting is only set by plexus-compiler-eclipse when both `targetVersion` AND `optimize` is set. [1]

Modify your pom like this and it should work:

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version> <!-- or 3.0 -->
    <configuration>
        <compilerId>eclipse</compilerId>
        <source>1.6</source>
        <target>1.6</target>
        <optimize>true</optimize>   <!-- add this line! -->
```

I'm not sure why it was decided in plexus-compiler-eclipse that optimization would affect the compliance level, so this is in fact a workaround.

Also, this code is enough to trigger the issue:

```
class Foo {
    static enum MyEnum { A }

    void foo() {
        switch ( MyEnum.A ) { case A: }
    }
}
```

[1] https://github.com/sonatype/plexus-compiler/blob/master/plexus-compilers/plexus-compiler-eclipse/src/main/java/org/codehaus/plexus/compiler/eclipse/EclipseJavaCompiler.java#L156

Comment: Will test and confirm this tomorrow morning once back at work, but it looks like an early thank you is in order.

Comment: Woot! An honorary mention here! http://bo2framework.blogspot.gr/2013/06/mavenized.html

Answer (score 0):

Don't use eclipse compiler in Maven build. If you omit the line

```
    <compilerId>eclipse</compilerId>
```

everything works fine, which shows that this is a problem specific to the eclipse compiler.

Comment: My maven configuration uses eclipse compiler. Java7 is not an option. I do not see why rt1==rt2 only when the enum is an inner class of the class doing the switch. Normal JDK compiles the specific classes, it looks like a bug of plexus-compiler-eclipse plugin.

Comment: @dkateros: Sorry, I completely changed my answer as I detected that I was led into a wrong direction. But as I said, it will be fine when not using eclipse compiler. Or is there a special reason that you use it instead of the regular JDK? One should always try to have the maven build IDE agnostic.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, the build will fail with numerous problems without the eclipse compiler :/ I posted the problem on the plexus users mailing list.

Comment: The eclipse compiler can read java 6 source and generate java 5 byte code.  That is relevant to us.

Comment: dkateros: can you give a link to the plexus users mailing list - and your question to it?
In can also find a dead link for the archive.

Comment: @kutzi missed this somehow, anyway, this is the post: http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/maven-compiler-plugin-compilation-failure-with-plexus-eclipse-compiler-td5755885.html